# Bitwise commands such as Bitor with many inputs?

Tags: matlab, bit-manipulation

Matlab takes only two inputs with bitwise commands such as [`bitor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitor.html). `bitor(1,2)` returns `3` and `bitor(1,2,4)` does not return `7` but:

> ASSUMEDTYPE must be an integer type name.

Currently, I create for-loops to basically create a bitwise command to take as many inputs as needed. I feel the for-loops for this kind of thing is reinvention of the wheel.

Is there some easy way of creating the bitwise operations with many inputs?

**Currently** an example with some random numbers, must return 127

```
indices=[1,23,45,7,89,100];
indicesOR=0;
for term=1:length(indices)
    indicesOR=bitor(indicesOR,indices(term));
end
```

Comment: It would useful to know the reason for downvote. There must be some steel way to do this, I doubt whether the matured way is to create looping solution each time.

Comment: What is `C`? Please provide input and desired output. Already had a look at [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)? -> *... fun can also be a handle to any binary element-wise function not listed above.*

Comment: +1 For well-explained question, attempted solution, runnable code

Comment: @thewaywewalk I can'y see how `bsxfun` is relevant to this problem - can you shed some light on this?

Comment: @hhh have you considered applying `bitor` in a "tree"-fashion/order rather than sequentially? can reduce to log number of operations

Comment: @Shai - I didn't got his problem entirely, but considered bsxfun first. If its useless, nevermind ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind getting strings involved (may be slow):

```
indicesOR  = bin2dec(char(double(any(dec2bin(indices)-'0'))+'0'));
```

This uses `dec2bin` to convert to strings of `'0'` and `'1'`; converts to numbers 0 and 1 by subtracting `'0'`; applys an "or" operation column-wise using `any`; and then converts back.

For AND (instead of OR): replace `any` by `all`:

```
indicesAND = bin2dec(char(double(all(dec2bin(indices)-'0'))+'0'));
```

For XOR: use `rem(sum(...),2)`:

```
indicesXOR = bin2dec(char(double(rem(sum(dec2bin(indices)-'0'),2))+'0'))
```

*EDIT*: I just found out about functions `de2bi` and `bi2de` (Communications Toolbox),  which avoid using strings. However, they seem to be slower!

```
indicesOR  = bi2de(double(any(de2bi(indices))));
indicesAND = bi2de(double(all(de2bi(indices))));
indicesXOR = bi2de(double(rem(sum((de2bi(indices))));
```

---

Another approach is to define a recursive function, exploiting the fact that AND, OR, XOR operations are (bit-wise) associative, that is, x OR y OR z equals (x OR y) OR z. The operation to be applied is passed as a function handle.

```
function r = bafun(v, f)
%BAFUN  Binary Associative Function
%   r = BAFUN(v,f)
%   v is a vector with at least two elements
%   f is a handle to a function that operates on two numbers

if numel(v) > 2
    r = bafun([f(v(1), v(2)) v(3:end)], f);
else
    r = f(v(1), v(2));
end
```

Example:

```
>> bafun([1,23,45,7,89,100], @bitor)
ans =
   127
```

Comment: I feel someone may have thought about some general solution working with all bitwise operations in Matlab, I understand this so that it works only in this special case but not with other operations. Anyway +1 for the start and Merry Christmas!

Comment: @hhh Another possibility is to define a recursive function, exploiting the fact that OR, AND, XOR are associative operations. The operation to be applied is passed as a function handle. See new update

Comment: Does Matlab handle (tail) recursion well?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I don't know... what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @LuisMendo: Your recursive function, when applied to a large vector, will result in very deep call nesting, possibly overflowing the stack.  Even if it doesn't overflow, there will be considerable overhead in making each of these calls.  Unless, of course, Matlab performs [TCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call_optimization).